# Finding two curves with intersection included in a specified neighborhood

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $V$ be a complex projective surface and $U$ an analytic neighborhood of $x\in V$.

How can I prove that there are two smooth curves $C_1$ and $C_2$ s.t. $C_1\cap C_2\subset U$ ?

Comment: Is $U$ Zariski open ? Do you want $C_1, C_2$ be smooth ?

Comment: $U$ is analytic neighborhood and the curves need to be smooth, yes.

Comment: x needs to be the intersection point of $C_1$ and $C_2$?

Comment: No, it doesn't.